# Find the volume bounded by $z=(x^2+y^2)^2$ and $z=x$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

My idea so far is to take a double integral of the curve and a double integral of the plane over the area of their projection onto the x-y plane. This seems easier to do in cylindrical polar coordinates? But then what do I take the region R over which to integrate as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cylindrical coordinates indeed make this problem much easier. First notice that the region is bounded between angles $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ (where the positive $x$-axis has angle 0). For a given angle $-\pi/2\leq\theta\leq\pi/2$, we can find the corresponding bounds for $r$ by setting
$$x=(x^2+y^2)^2$$
and substituting $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$:
\begin{align}
r\cos\theta&=(r^2\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta)^2 \\
&=r^4 \\
&\Rightarrow{}r=(\cos\theta)^{1/3}.
\end{align}
So $r$ is ranging from 0 to $(\cos\theta)^{1/3}$. Now for a given $r$ and $\theta$, $z$ is bounded below by the surface $z=r^4$ and above by $z=r\cos\theta$. So the triple integral is
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{(\cos\theta)^{1/3}}\int_{r^4}^{r\cos\theta}rdzdrd\theta &= \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{(\cos\theta)^{1/3}}\big(r^2\cos\theta-r^5\big)drd\theta \\
&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\bigg[\frac{r^3}{3}\cos\theta-\frac{r^6}{6}\bigg]_{0}^{(\cos\theta)^{1/3}}d\theta \\
&=\frac{1}{6}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}(\cos\theta)^2d\theta \\
&=\frac{1}{6}\bigg[\frac{\theta}{2}+\frac{\sin(2\theta)}{4}\bigg]_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \\
&=\boxed{\frac{\pi}{12}}.
\end{align}